# How put minutes value in axis Y in report builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a graph and I want to put the minutes on the Y axis, it only gives me data that I do not understand.
Does anyone know how to represent the minutes as in the bars on the Y axis?

See how it is currently, I want minutes on the Y axis

[image: Current Y-axis display]

This is the data or result of my query that are represents in the graph

[image: Report Data]

Design to add data

[image: Report design]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click vertical axis, select properties, select number, select default.
Right mouse click vertical axis, select properties, select interval type, select Minutes.

Comment: Thanks SuperSimmer 44 but it shows me the time like 12:14 AM, 12:15 AM, 12: 16 AM and 12:17 AM and I want you to show me only 1..., 14,15,16,17 so on.

Comment: I had to manipulate the original dataset to put the minutes into a separated out column. Added this into original sql select statement: DATEPART(mi,tiempo) as minutes. and then adjust vertical axis properties to default settings and hey presto it worked.